# Unable to update Laravel past version 8.48.0

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Composer Update has been working perfectly to update Laravel and my dependencies up until I tried to update to 8.49.0. When I run composer update now I'm getting:

```
witt@Witts-MPB ag % composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies                                 
Lock file operations: 0 installs, 23 updates, 0 removals
  - Upgrading facade/ignition (2.10.2 => 2.11.0)
  - Upgrading fakerphp/faker (v1.14.1 => v1.15.0)
  - Upgrading filp/whoops (2.13.0 => 2.14.0)
  - Upgrading guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.8.2 => 2.0.0)
  - Downgrading intervention/image (2.5.1 => 2.2.2)
  - Upgrading laminas/laminas-escaper (2.7.0 => 2.8.0)
  - Upgrading laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge (1.2.0 => 1.3.0)
  - Upgrading laravel/framework (v8.48.0 => v8.50.0)
  - Upgrading league/commonmark (1.6.4 => 1.6.5)
  - Upgrading league/flysystem (1.1.3 => 1.1.4)
  - Upgrading monolog/monolog (2.2.0 => 2.3.0)
  - Upgrading myclabs/php-enum (1.8.0 => 1.8.3)
  - Upgrading nesbot/carbon (2.49.0 => 2.50.0)
  - Upgrading nikic/php-parser (v4.10.5 => v4.11.0)
  - Upgrading phpunit/phpunit (9.5.5 => 9.5.6)
  - Upgrading spatie/dropbox-api (1.19.0 => 1.19.1)
  - Upgrading stripe/stripe-php (v7.85.0 => v7.88.0)
  - Upgrading symfony/error-handler (v5.3.0 => v5.3.3)
  - Upgrading symfony/http-foundation (v5.3.2 => v5.3.3)
  - Upgrading symfony/http-kernel (v5.3.2 => v5.3.3)
  - Upgrading symfony/string (v5.3.2 => v5.3.3)
  - Upgrading symfony/translation (v5.3.2 => v5.3.3)
  - Upgrading symfony/var-dumper (v5.3.2 => v5.3.3)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 23 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading laravel/framework (v8.50.0)
  - Downloading facade/ignition (2.11.0)
  - Downloading stripe/stripe-php (v7.88.0)
  - Downloading filp/whoops (2.14.0)
  - Upgrading symfony/var-dumper (v5.3.2 => v5.3.3): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/string (v5.3.2 => v5.3.3): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading monolog/monolog (2.2.0 => 2.3.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/http-foundation (v5.3.2 => v5.3.3): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/error-handler (v5.3.0 => v5.3.3): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/http-kernel (v5.3.2 => v5.3.3): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/translation (v5.3.2 => v5.3.3): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading nesbot/carbon (2.49.0 => 2.50.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading league/flysystem (1.1.3 => 1.1.4): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading league/commonmark (1.6.4 => 1.6.5): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading laravel/framework (v8.48.0 => v8.50.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading facade/ignition (2.10.2 => 2.11.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading fakerphp/faker (v1.14.1 => v1.15.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.8.2 => 2.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge (1.2.0 => 1.3.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading stripe/stripe-php (v7.85.0 => v7.88.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading nikic/php-parser (v4.10.5 => v4.11.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading myclabs/php-enum (1.8.0 => 1.8.3): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading filp/whoops (2.13.0 => 2.14.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading laminas/laminas-escaper (2.7.0 => 2.8.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading phpunit/phpunit (9.5.5 => 9.5.6): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading spatie/dropbox-api (1.19.0 => 1.19.1): Extracting archive
  - Downgrading intervention/image (2.5.1 => 2.2.2): Extracting archive
Generating optimized autoload files
composer/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...
composer/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

   Error 

  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share()

  at vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/ImageServiceProviderLaravel5.php:51
     47▕             'image'
     48▕         );
     49▕ 
     50▕         // create image
  ➜  51▕         $app['image'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
     52▕             return new ImageManager($app['config']->get('image'));
     53▕         });
     54▕ 
     55▕         $app->alias('image', 'Intervention\Image\ImageManager');

      +8 vendor frames 
  9   artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

The first thing I notice is that the intervention/image package is being downgraded (see output above).

I tried modifying composer.lock directly to keep that package at version 2.5.1, but that did not resolve the error.

I'm running PHP version 7.4.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any suggestions on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

This problem was caused because Laravel 8.49.0 updates guzzlehttp from 1.8.2 to 2.0.0, and intervention/image is not compatible with that release.

There is a patch to intervention/image to address the issue, mentioned on [this thread.](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/1095)

However, the patch is currently on a development branch.

To fix this:

1. run composer update, receiving the error described above
2. modify composer.json, adding:

   "minimum-stability": "dev",

   "prefer-stable": true

This allows packages at development stability level if necessary.

3. Run composer require intervention/image:"master"